# Is it possible to get a grass block using a dirt-only Minecraft world and naturally spawning mobs?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

There is a Minecraft world with only dirt.
Difficulty is normal mode.

Is it possible to only use mobs that naturally spawn and this dirt to get grass to spawn?

Comment: Naturally, as in not /summon'ed ? You could always summon an enderman holding a grass block in hand...

Comment: @SF. Yes, not summoned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I don't think there is any way to grow grass except for using grass next to it.
It's all according to this: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Grass_Block